# Algorithm to traverse several locations finding the shortest route

Tags: php, algorithm, graph-traversal

I am creating a program for tourists. They will leave the hotel and go to lets say 3 different places (B, C, D). I need to find the shortest route to traverse location B, C, and D. The end point is not important it can be either of them.

Can [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) do this?

I need to implement the algorithm using PHP.

Comment: your problem sounds like a tsp
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dijkstra's algorithm can solve this problem. I am not sure if it is optimal. But at least, it solves your problem. In the worst case, you can enumerate all orders with which you reach each node (i.e., `BCD`, `BDC`, `CDB`, `CBD`, `DBC`, `DCB`). Then run the Dijkstra's algorithm to get the shortest path. Take the order `BCD` for example, run the Dijkstra's to get the shortest from the hotel to `B`, from `B` to `C`, at last from `C` to `D`, sum them up to get the shortest path for this order. The shortest one within all orders is the optimal solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice